# How to toggle column visibility based on hidden input value?

Tags: jquery, datatables

in my table every column header (except the first one) has an hidden input field named 'group'. I want to implement buttons to toggle the visibility of specific columns based on in which group they are. I'm stuck at finding the right column-selector to get all columns where e.g. the input field value is "group1".

At the moment my buttons look like this and with simple selector like ':gt(0)' it works perfectly.

```
buttons: [
    {
        extend: 'columnToggle',
        text: 'Toggle Group1',
        columns: //get all columns with input value equals 'group1'
    }
]
```

I already tried a few things with jquery selectors, but i cant get it to work properly.

I have build a little test case with datatables live :
[Testcase](http://live.datatables.net/novikubo/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output)

Thanks for the help

Comment: Could you use CSS classes instead of a hidden group? $('th.group1')?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using hidden inputs, have you tried applying a class to each column and then toggling as follows?:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    columns: [
    { className: "group1" },
    { className: "group2" },
    { className: "group1" },
    { className: "group2" },
    { className: "group2" },
    { className: "group2" },
  ],
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
      {
        extend: 'columnToggle',
        text: 'Toggle Group1',
        columns: '.group1'
      },
      {
        extend: 'columnToggle',
        text: 'Toggle Group2',
        columns: '.group2'
      }
    ]
  });
} );
```

A live example can be found here:
http://live.datatables.net/howaxeju/1/edit

See further the following page regarding applying classes to columns:
https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.className

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
   dom: 'Bfrtip',
   buttons: [
     {
       extend: 'columnToggle',
       text: 'Toggle Group1',
       columns: $('#example thead th input[value="group1"]').closest('th')  
     }
   ]
});
```

See [updated example](http://live.datatables.net/novikubo/5/edit) for code and demonstration.

However it would be better to use class names for `th` elements instead and toggle columns by class name, see excellent [answer by Zejji Zejji](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35444061/3549014).